Do Japan's "Kami" have a divine rank?
Do Japan's "Kami" have a divine rank?
Japanese Shintoism is a type of animism, and it seems that Kami exists in rice fields, toilets, and even grains of rice. Will all of them have divine rank?

Kami have divine rank.
The D&D 3e sourcebook Deities and Demigods, p.9, describes animism of the Japanese Shinto type. The term "kami" isn't used specifically, but it does refer to a system of divinity where spirits exist in all things, which would describe kami.

Spirits represent the whole range of divine ranks, from 0 to 20. Animism is certainly an example of an infinite pantheon, since new spirits come into being all the time. The spirits probably gain their power through worship—a spirit that is not worshiped does not die, but rarely rises above divine rank 0.

It's not entirely clear whether the section means all kami have divine rank, or just some, but it is a plausible interpretation that even the lowliest kami start at divine rank 0.
